# Schedule Autosys job in UI for 2ndtuesday of every month

Tags: autosys

I have a job, needs to Run only on 2nd Tuesday of every month.

can someone help, all responses are appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Create an extended calendar, and assign to the respective jobs

```
extended_calendar: Tue2_Monthly
description: 2nd Tuesday Monthly
workday: mo,tu,we,th,fr
non_workday:
holiday:
holcal:
cyccal:
condition: tue#2
```